# How to nest multiple SQL queries?

Tags: sql, performance, subquery

Can someone show me how to nest these queries into one entire query? Right now, Im just running each of these (up to 10) one at a time but I want to learn how to run this query in one single shot.

```
Dim queryString1 As String = 
"SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD 
 FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN 
 WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " 
 AND ACTIVE = 1 
 GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""


Dim queryString2 As String = 
"SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD 
 FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN 
 WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " 
 AND ACTIVE = 1  
 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' 
 GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME 
 ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""


Dim queryString3 As String = 
"SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD 
 FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN 
 WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " 
 AND ACTIVE = 1  
 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' 
 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' 
 GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME 
 ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a few UNION statements:

```
Dim queryString1 As String = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD
  FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND ACTIVE = 1 
  GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & vbCrLf & _

" UNION " & vbCrLf & _

"SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD 
  FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN 
  WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND ACTIVE = 1 
  AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' 
  GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & vbCrLf & _

" UNION " & vbCrLf & _

"SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD 
  FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN 
  WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND ACTIVE = 1 
  AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' 
  GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text
```

(of course, you will want to remove the extra line-breaks that I added for readability)

Comment: Question: How can I ge the itemID of the second union query? I thought if i used CType(Reader.Item(2), String) I would be able to get the second employee but im getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array." error

Comment: ItemID is not part of the result set.  You would need to add it to each of the three queries.  Keep in mind that Reader.Item(2) refers to the third item in the SELECT statement (and you only specified two items).

Answer (score 1):

Let's check what this queries are returning:

(all three uses the same  group by  and the same order )

1- Returns all the "active" employees at "areaFooBar"

2- Returns all the "active" employees at "areaFooBar" MINUS one employee

3- Returns all the "active" employees at "areaFooBar" MINUS two employee

You can do this kind of filtering in the code.
You don't have to run query 2 or query 3.
Re-iterate the resultset of query 1 and filter the employee you do not want to include.

You can have to read it from database each time, then you can use one queryString if you 
add one more parameter to your query i.e.: comma-separated-list.Text

```
Dim queryString1 As String = 
"
 SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD 
 FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN 
 WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " 
 AND ACTIVE = 1 
 EMPLOYEE_NAME NOT IN ( " & comma-separated-list.Text & " ) 
 GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
```

Comment: could you elaborate more on the comma-separated-list.Text part? so, this is all I would need to enter, in the query?

Comment: Declare a varchar variable as comma-separated-list. You can populate this variable (comma-separated-list) with the "LblStckRnkX.Text" values.  i.e: If you will include no LblStckRnk Text, set the comma-separeted-list to empty string. If you will pass LblStckRnk1.Text and LblStckRnk2.Text and LblStckRnk3.Text; then set the comma-departed-list to  [ LblStckRnk1.Text + "," + LblStckRnk2.Text + ", " LblStckRnk3.Text ] .